# Android windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" not working in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I have a button layout that should show at bottom, even when the keyboard comes it should show above keyboard
So I have added 
$windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
in AndroidManifest.xml for the Activity
Now this works fine in portrait mode, but fails in landscape.

Comment: This happens because the surfaceChanged method is not called if the app is in full screen or in landscape.
This bug was added in 2009 in the Android bug report system.  
The landscape issue was fixed on Android 3.0
There must be a workaround, but I don't know it, sorry..

Comment: ok thanks perroloco.
We changed our implementation

Comment: how do you solved this problem chin87?

Comment: I'm not ever seeing surfaceChanged, even in 4.x, when in landscape+full screen. :|